# XMLSpy behaviour of xsl:copy-of and element set as fixed/qualified in schema

Tags: xsd, xslt-2.0, xmlspy, altova

I'm currently using Altova XMLSpy to convert a XML file using a XSLT 2.0 transformation sheet.
The problem I'm experiencing is that the source XML has some attributes defined in the schema as "fixed" and "qualified" so after the transformation they appear in the result XML. I know that's the default behaviour but the problem is those attributes have a namespace prefix that's not being copied so the result XML is not valid... 
Actually I would like to disable the automatic generation of all "fixed" elements, is that possible?

Best Regards
Vlax

**EDIT:**

Here an example of the schema I'm using

PREMIS:
http://www.loc.gov/standards/premis/v2/premis.xsd

(notice the the xsl:import to http://www.loc.gov/standards/xlink/xlink.xsd)

Here the XML and XSLT to download (they are too long to publish as code):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11304697/Premis/Premis_Identity_Transformation.zip

Notice that in Identtiy_Transform_Result.xml in some element the fixed qualified attribute "xlink:type" is being output as type="simple", so no namespace prefix...

Comment: Can you post some samples of the input XML you have? Do you need it to be associated with a schema for your XSLT transformation? The only way you could get schema created attributes is in my view by validating input or output against a schema and if you simply don't associate input files with a schema the problem should be gone.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Actually I'm using some schema-aware features (data types + id() function) in my transformation so I would like to keep the schema associated to the source xml.  
I will add an example of the schemas I'm using on the main post so you can see by yourself.  
THxs!